# Check if date has already been parsed with moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am passing down a date string which needs to be parsed appropriately with `moment`. The problem is in some circumstances it is getting parsed twice, which causes it to become `undefined`.

this is what the code currently looks like:

```
moment.tz(dt, 'MMMM D, YYYY', timezone).toDate()
```

When I parse it the second time, I get:

> moment.invalid(/* 2018-09-21T05:00:00.000Z */)

Which causes when I do `toDate()` to become `undefined`.

while the first time I will get exactly what I expect:

> '2019-02-01T05:00:00.000Z'

Before doing any of this I would like to check if it already if in the format I expect it to be. How do I do this?

Comment: why is it being parsed twice? It kinda sounds like a logical flaw. Is there no better way to prevent that by altering the flow of the code?

Comment: It has to do with conversions of data. Sometimes I convert it to json and other times from json to csv and other times directly to csv. Which is why I need to know how to check if the data is already in the format I expect it to be, that would be my remedy for the logical flaw.

Comment: Instead of checking the type of the variable before parsing the date (I believe it would be the answer you are looking for with this question), I would try to understand why the function is being called when it is not needed, and then fix that.

Comment: I guess you're changing the date string at the same time as changing the data format (i.e. doing it at the same time as changing from JSON to CSV or something). Maybe you could separate those two processes, I don't know, I don't have enough info to make a judgment. But if there's no better option, you could potentially use the [isValid()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) method to check if the parsing worked before calling `toDate()`

Comment: Maybe you should show us a bit more code.

Comment: The code `moment.tz(dt, 'MMMM D, YYYY', timezone).toDate()` returns a Date object. So all you need to do is test the type of the value before attempting to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use the [isValid()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) method to check if the parsing worked before calling `toDate()`. Demo:

```js
var timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";
var dt = 'Sept 21, 2018';
var m = moment.tz(dt, 'MMMM D, YYYY', timezone);
var converted = m.toDate().toString();
console.log(converted);

var x = moment.tz(converted, 'MMMM D, YYYY', timezone);
console.log(x.isValid());
//if parsing worked, use the new value
if (x.isValid()) {
  console.log(x.toDate());
}
// if not, assume it's already the correct format and just use that
else
{
  console.log(converted);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```